# Don't know how to use LocalDate

Tags: java, dayofweek, localdate

I'm studying java and I need to do a code with this: Create a constructor, and if the date is monday, the variable *total* will have 10% of discount.

But I'm getting error when I put a date in my main, and have no idea how create this boolean of local date "monday". Can someone help me?

My code:

```
package pedido;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class pedido {

    private int numero;
    private LocalDate datapedido;
    private double quantidade, valor, total;
    private boolean sunday;

    public pedido(int m, LocalDate j, double p, double k) {
        this.numero = m;
        this.datapedido = j;
        this.quantidade = p;
        this.valor = k;
    }
        
    
    public void totalpedido() {
        if(sunday == true) {
            total = (this.valor * this.quantidade) * 0.9;
            System.out.printf("Por hoje ser domingo o total ficou: R$%.2f", total);
        }
        if(sunday == false) {
            total = (this.valor * this.quantidade);
            System.out.printf("O total ficou: %.2f", total);
        }
    }
    
}
```

and the main:

```
package pedido;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        pedido p1 = new pedido(111, 2021-09-26, 2, 36.50);
        p1.totalpedido();
        
        pedido p2 = new pedido(222, 2021-09-23, 1, 13.25);
        p2.totalpedido();
            
        
    }

}
```

Errors:

> ```
> Multiple markers at this line
>   - The constructor pedido(int, int, int, double) is 
>    undefined
>   - The literal 09 of type int is out of range
> ```

Comment: Instead of `if(monday == true) {` and `if(monday == false) {` just use `if(monday) {`… `else {`.

Comment: "I'm getting error" What error, specifically? Read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 6):

The `LocalDate` class has a method `getDayOfWeek()` which returns a `DayOfWeek` enum.  So you can just write

```
if (datapedido.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
     // it's Sunday
}
```

To actually create your `LocalDate` object, you can write

```
LocalDate.of(2021, 9, 23)
```

which is an expression of type `LocalDate`.

Comment: OP had Sunday in the question at one point, then edited it to Monday after I'd started answering.